# python irc bot, unable to join server

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I want to host a simple irc bot in python with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import socket

HOST = 'irc.gamesurge.net'
PORT = 6667
NICK = 'test_bot'
IDENT = 'testbot'
REALNAME = 'TestBot'
OWNER = 'Test'
CHANNELINIT = '#test_channel'

readbuffer = ''

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.send('NICK %sn' % NICK)
sock.send('USER %s %s bla :%sn' % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))


while True:
    line = sock.recv(500)
    if line:
        print line
        if line.find('GameSurge') != -1:
            print "joining..."
            print"current line: "+line
            sock.send('JOIN %sn' % CHANNELINIT)
```

but regardless of which gamesurge server I choose to connect, it always gives me this error:

`ERROR :Closing Link:  by NuclearFallout.WA.US.GameSurge.net (Registration Timeout)`

Here's what the server returns:

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname
NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking Ident
NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname

NOTICE AUTH :*** No ident response

ERROR :Closing Link:  by NuclearFallout.WA.US.GameSurge.net (Registration Timeout)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
sock.send('NICK %sn' % NICK)
```

You're missing a `\` before that `n` - the end of a command is a newline, not a `n`. Same for the rest of your lines.

```
sock.send('NICK %s\n' % NICK)
sock.send('USER %s %s bla :%s\n' % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))
```

and so on. That said, why reinvent the wheel? There are many IRC bot frameworks/modules available that take the guesswork out of the process and let you focus on writing the actual functionality for the bot.

Comment: it still throws me the same error, but along with this ``Prometheus.UK.EU.GameSurge.net 513 choi_bot :Your client may not be compatible with this server.``

Comment: also, what framework would you recommend?  and any example code?

Comment: [willie](http://willie.dftba.net/) is one example of a fairly mature IRC bot framework.